# Office-js: Extracting chart data range in Excel

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm writing Excel addin using Office-js and I need to persist data of selected chart on server.
I know that I can save whole chart as base64 encoded image, but I'd prefer to get chart source data for future chart recreation (using different styling/template).

In current office-js API, is there any method for getting chart data range, so I can read values from worksheet, instead of exporting chart as image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, Unfortunately our API don't support this scenario and this is a known feature gap. So would you please provide us feedback via https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563 and upvote for this feature. thanks for your support.

Comment: I created a FEATURE backlog 3888925 for this request, we will prioritze this work based on upvote from the uservoice, thanks